# "this month" highlighted with "today"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, recent-activity, usability

I don't know if you can see it as well, but I get "this month" highlighted at the same time with "today" (I clicked today).

Now, I agree that, since today is the first of the month, today is also the whole month, and it makes kind of sense that both are highlighted, but was it really intended? A tab widget (which is what that set of entries appears to emulate) does not work this way.

[alt text http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/739/todaythismonth.png](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/739/todaythismonth.png)

Comment: Why is it "this month" and not "last 30 days"? I always want to view the last X days.. Showing me only the last day, or the last 30, depending on when I click it makes zero sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's intentional. The links for "today" and "this month" are identical:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/youruserid?StartDate=2010-02-01&EndDate=2010-02-01
```

It's really the date range you are clicking on/selecting, not a specific tab (at least, not when two tabs contain the same data).

Answer (score 1):

Given that logic, `this week` should be highlighted every Sunday.

Comment: That depends when the week starts.... Could be that they decided it starts on Sunday and nobody ever noted that. hardly, I assume.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've checked, and it starts on Monday

Comment: It doesn't... compare your rep/responses (and the URLs) for "today" vs. "this week" -- they will be different.

Comment: Ok, changed my answer to be more correct.

Comment: It would make awfully more sense to highlight "this week" on Mondays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it really was intended, but I'd say it's a feature, not a bug.