# Multiple notification sub-tabs are highlighted at the same time

Tags: bug, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“this month” highlighted with “today”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37756/this-month-highlighted-with-today)

When either "Today" or "This Month" is selected, both sub-tabs are highlighted.

Comment: I imagine this is only for today because "Today" and "This Month" are both the same span of time (it is only June 1st). It affects not just Favorites, but all Recent Activity tabs.

Comment: @ccomet: BAH! You're right. It's like this in all the summary tabs. Although, I have to say that it makes no sense why both sub-tabs get highlighted just because it's the 1st of the month.

Comment: @ccomet: Now I'm curious, but we'll have to wait until Sunday to see if that holds true. In the meantime, I'm going to edit my question. I can't find any other instances of someone reporting this as a "bug," so I'll leave this open for others to find. Do you want to move your comments to an answer here?

Comment: Just chiming in to say I'm getting this error too, in both Chrome and IE. I also noticed that I was updated regarding questions I had marked as a favorite. Could something have trickled in as part of that new feature?

Comment: @Dillie-O: Yes, it's a [new feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20954/have-an-option-to-watch-a-question-without-posting/51824#51824). I also created a feature-request to [disable the favorite notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51947/allow-users-to-opt-out-of-all-favorite-notifications).

Comment: Alright, converted comment to an answer. However, someone else posted a duplicate, which pointed out [that this was pointed out even earlier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37756/this-month-highlighted-with-today). Kinda makes me wish I could retract that conversion to the correct position in the comments, now.

Comment: @ccomet: Nice find. I have flagged for mod attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the nature of today's date (June 1st), the reason both "Today" and "This Month" are highlighted is because they are the same span of time. Each sub-tab in Recent Activity doesn't seem to be a separate page, but just different evaluations of the values for `StartDate` and `EndDate` in the query string. I would guess that it is one page that dynamically updates its contents based on this, and selects which tabs to highlight to reflect the values.

"This Month" cannot span past the current day; only time which has already existed can be recorded. So in this case, all "This Month" covers is "6/1/2010 - 6/1/2010", which is also what "Today" evaluates to. I would imagine that likewise, "This Week" will be highlighted alongside "Today" at the start of every week, since that too only evaluates as far as time has occurred.